# Minimize the app when click the back button android

Tags: android, performance

I created an app that calls the `onPause()` when the back button is pressed.

As following way..

```
protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        // Notification show in status bar

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon).setContentTitle("TNLRadio")
                .setContentText("");
        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        // Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Intent resultIntent = this.getIntent();

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int mId = 0;
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());

        this.unregisterReceiver(UIStateManager.getInsatance());
        // unregister call listener
        UIStateManager.getInsatance().onPause(this);
    }
```

I want to do the same things when click the back button ... which is in `onBackPress()`. I call the `onPause()` method inside the `onBackPress()` method.

Then I got the error as follows:

```
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.ironone.streaming.evt.UIStateManager@4153d788
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:628)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1130)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:354)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at com.ironone.streaming.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:567)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at com.ironone.streaming.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:866)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2099)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2633)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2329)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1957)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3546)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3519)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2603)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me as soon as possible

Comment: have you registered the receiver in onCreate() ?

Comment: can you really call onPause() manually?

Comment: no you can't. that's what the exception is actually telling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, completely remove the `onBackPressed()`. Then, try inserting the following code into your `onKeyDown()` as follows.
(if you don't have a such a method already. Just copy past the following code)

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            return true;
    }

    // your other related codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is on the line `"onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:866)"`. Use `Ctrl+L` to go to it and please provide the code `onBackpressed()` with the line 866.

Moreover your error is "`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: "` so you either have unregistered too early your listener or did not set up correctly a listener.

Please try to paginate the Error log when you paste it. I personally do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148575/fragment-getactivity-returns-null-because-onattach-not-called-yet-how-to-synchr)

**Edit:** thanks @trinimon to have edit the code for you :) & @RiteshGune pour avoir éditer le mien :D

Answer (score 0):

Please read the error log carefully, and here's the cause of the exception:

```
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:354)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at com.ironone.streaming.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:567)
08-28 13:45:34.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14153):    at com.ironone.streaming.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:866)
```

So, the root cause lies in the line 567 in your `MainActivity.java` file, it seems that the `UIStateManager.getInsatance()` receiver has already been unregistered (somewhere in your code).

And here's a post that addresses the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165070/receiver-not-registered-exception-error).